# Unable to access “67 GB Volume”

Tags: mount, ntfs

I plugged a 64 GB pendrive into my computer but the system shows 67 GB, and it is not working in my system. It shows the following errors. What should I do. Is the pendrive corrupted or not?

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/rajat/0CFBC19E66F9E9BC: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/rajat/0CFBC19E66F9E9BC"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

---

Comment: Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/912703/how-to-fix-corrupted-ntfs) helps?

Comment: Did you run `chkdsk /f` as instructed? Do not run ntfsfix in Ubuntu.

Comment: It could be a fake-- someone may've munged the disk header information to make it look larger than it actually is, and Ubuntu has spotted this.